# Defining a variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to declare an **immutable** variable in Haskell:

```
let a = [1, 2]
main = print $ sum a
```

but it claims

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

what's up with that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`let` is not used at the top level definition. There are several ways to correct your programs, some of which are

```
a = [1,2]
main = print $ sum a
```

Or

```
main = do
  let a = [1,2]
  print $ sum a
```

Or

```
main = let a = [1,2] in print $ sum a
```

The usual source of confusion for people trying to use `let` at the top level is when they are trying to convert some tested expression in `ghci` to actual source file.

`let` can be used when you are working inside a monad. ghci and `main` works inside `IO` monad, so you can write something like `let a = [1,2]` in ghci.

Comment: I'm not doing it inside ghci or main.

Comment: why are you saying that if it won't help me?

Comment: @MariusKavansky You don't use let for a top-level definition within a source file.

Comment: The comment about ghci is something extra which usually confuse people who try to convert expression tested in ghci into haskell programs.

Comment: `let` is also used for `let ... in ...` expressions, e.g. `main = let a = [1,2] in print $ sum a` would be another valid alternative.

Comment: StackOverflow is a collaboratively edited Q&A site, not a one on one tutoring site. By providing an explanation for all of the cases when and when not to use the `let` construct, this answer is more useful to anyone who happens to see this question when trying to find information about that syntax.